# I want to get array using given min , max range

Tags: javascript, arrays, range, push

I want to get an output array beginning with min value and ending with max value => `[5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

But I get only min value in new array => `[5]`. Why does this happen?

```
function arrayFromRange(min , max){
    const newArray = [];

    for( let x = min ; x <= max; x++ ){
      newArray.push(x);
      return newArray;
    }
}
```

```
const newarray1 = arrayFromRange(5,10);

console.log(newarray1);
```

Comment: Because you are `return`ing early (inside your loop rather than outside). Moev the `return newArray;` line outside of your loop and your function will work :)

Comment: You return inside the loop, so the first iteration the function will exit and the next iterations will never start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop in JS only returns first value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503166/for-loop-in-js-only-returns-first-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return your `newArray` *inside* the for loop, having only added the first item, in this case 5.

Solution is to move the return out of the foor loop, i.e.

```
function arrayFromRange(min , max){
    const newArray = [];

    for( let x = min ; x <= max; x++ ){
      newArray.push(x);
    } //                             <--swap these
    return newArray; //              <-- two lines
}
```